# Unsure about mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if this was correct? I have a feeling that it isnt and would like to know the best way to fix it.

```
$query= mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$email'"));
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $firstname = $row['firstname'];
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try it? What happens when you do? That will tell you if it is correct.

Comment: Yes, your code is wrong, this part: "$query= mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("

Comment: Sql Injection and using the deprecated mysql over mysqli or pdo.

Comment: mysqli is officially recommended to use because in latest version of php, mysql is deprecated.

Comment: This is worth reading: ["Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/358906).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning the number of rows to `$query`, whereas you should be assigning the return value of `mysql_query()` because `mysql_fetch_array()` requires a result identifier as its argument.

Other issues:

- Usage of the deprecated MySQL library. Consider upgrading to PDO or MySQLi
- The source of `$email` is not shown but there may be an SQL Injection vulnerability. Use a prepared statement in PDO or MySQLi to prevent this.
- Check the return value before you try to fetch rows. If your query failed, you would be passing a boolean to `mysql_fetch_array()`.

Refactored to show the proper logic (but still should not be used because it's deprecated):

```
$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='" . mysql_real_escape_string($email) . "'");

if($query){ // check the return value
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $firstname = $row['firstname'];
    }
}
```

MySQLi example using a prepared statement:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'dbname');
if($stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = ?')){
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($result = $stmt->get_result()){
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $firstname = $row['firstname'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3495551 added example.

Answer (score 2):

**MySQL:**

```
$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$email'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $firstname = $row['firstname'];
}
```

**MySQLi:**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root_user", "root_password", "database_name");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email ='$email'")) {        
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      $firstname = $row['firstname'];
    }
    $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: +1 for answering the question and not getting off-topic with code recommendations. Rare to see these days.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you need that mysql_num_rows? I highly doubt that this will work. I guess you can't combine mysql functions, but can't be sure since I haven't use mysql functions for years and neither should you since they're deprecated. Try using mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query= mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$email'"));
```

should be

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$email'");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please move away from using mysql and start using mysqli or PDO, as the mysql function is depreciated now.**

As for your query, here is an example:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); // The Connection

$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email ='$email'"; // MySQL Query
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query); // Perform the Query

 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data); // Work with the data using $row

  $firstname = $row['firstname'];
```

To display output:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {

  // do something to echo

 }
```